# Get data from table according to data from another table with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to show author details on a page.

Here is my typoscript to get the cruser_id of the page content:

```
    20 = CONTENT
    20{
        table = tt_content
        select{
         selectFields = cruser_id
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj{
         10 = TEXT  
         10{
         required=1      
         field=cruser_id
         }
        }
      }
```

How to get the username associated with the cruser_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't specify the context of your code, here's an example that just extends the code you provided.

```
20 = CONTENT
20 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    selectFields = cruser_id
  }
  renderObj = RECORDS
  renderObj {
    source.field = cruser_id 
    tables = be_users
    dontCheckPid = 1
    conf.be_users = TEXT
    conf.be_users {
      field = username
      noTrimWrap = || |
    }
  }
}
```

**EXPLANATION**: You are fetching the content using the `CONTENT` cObject and telling TYPO3 to render it as `RECORDS` cObject. This object now has user's UID available as `cruser_id` and can use it in its configuration using the `source.field`. `RECORDS` thus loads the record (with UID = cruser_id) from the `be_users` table and you tell TYPO3 to render it as a `TEXT` cObject. As it can be any cObject (e.g. COA), the output can be more complex, including other fields from the backend user's record.

---

**More complex example**

```
20 = CONTENT
20 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    selectFields = cruser_id, tstamp
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      field = tstamp
      date = j/n/Y
      noTrimWrap = |Last modified: ||
    }

    20 = RECORDS
    20 {
      source.field = cruser_id 
      tables = be_users
      dontCheckPid = 1
      conf.be_users = COA
      conf.be_users {
        stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |<br />Author: ||

        10 = TEXT
        10 {
          field = realName
        }

        20 = TEXT
        20 {
          field = username
          noTrimWrap = | (|)|
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Chiyou: Why do you think there is a mistake?

Comment: I didn't test it but can use use conf be users for a variable name? Space keystroke is allowed?

Comment: @Chiyou: `conf.be_users` is not a variable name. It's setting the way records are supposed to be rendered for the `be_users` table. See reference of the `RECORDS` object.

Comment: Then you have spelling mistake in 2nd line. You wrote [space] char between conf.be and users.

Comment: @Chiyou: You see a space in any of those two `conf.be_users`? I don't. [scratching head]

Comment: LOL! Maybe it's my browser. I'm mobile and yes I see space not when I get very close.

Comment: @Chiyou: Alright, that might be the explanation. :-) All in all, there shouldn't be any space.

Comment: @cascaval What should I do to fetch and display more than one field like realName, crdate etc??

Comment: @HarishAnchu: Nothing really. `RECORDS` fetches the whole record so you have all the fields available. You just have to use them. `conf.be_users` can be set to any **[cObject](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/7/)** so I suggest you turn it into a `COA` object containing several `TEXT` objects, each of them displaying the field you want.

Comment: @cascaval I want display more than one field from the primary table too(ie. tt_content).

Comment: @HarishAnchu: You can make it more complex by setting the `renderObj` to `COA` as well. I have added a new example.